# Update view on orientation change

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I have registered a orientationChangedEvent like this:

```
app.on(app.orientationChangedEvent, (args: OrientationChangedEventData) => {
  if (this.currentScreenWidth === screen.mainScreen.widthDIPs) {
    this.currentScreenWidth = screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs;
  } else {
    this.currentScreenWidth = screen.mainScreen.widthDIPs;
  }
  this.configureGrid();
});
```

I have the following template:

```
<GridLayout [rows]="rows" [columns]="columns">
<ng-container *ngFor="let card of cards">
  <StackLayout [row]="card.row" [col]="card.col" [colSpan]="card.colSpan">
    <kirby-card>
      <kirby-card-header [title]="'row: ' + card.row" [subtitle]="'col: ' + card.col">
      </kirby-card-header>
      <StackLayout class="content">
        <Label text="Here you can add stuff, which is cool."></Label>
      </StackLayout>
      <kirby-card-footer>
        <kirby-button label="Dummy Kirby Button" expand="block" shape="round" theme="cookbook"></kirby-button>
      </kirby-card-footer>
    </kirby-card>
  </StackLayout>
</ng-container>
```

and in my configureGrid method I update the rows, columns and cards properties, but my view is not updating, the view (GridLayout) simply display exactly the same as before the rotation. I have logged out all the data, and my data does change, so it seems the data binding does not understand that the data has changed.

Can I somehow force a update of the view, or how do I fix this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the data update with NgZone, and all is good.